# python: topic clusters with dendrogram

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a list of keywords that I want to regroup by clusters based on semantic meaning. I try to use `dendrogram`algorithm. So it's actually working well: it's returning the clusters ID, but I don't know how to associate every keyword to the appropriate cluster. Here is my code:

```
    def clusterize(self, keywords):
        preprocessed_keywords = normalize(keywords)

        # Generate TF-IDF vectors for the preprocessed keywords
        tfidf_matrix = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(preprocessed_keywords)
    
        # Use hierarchical agglomerative clustering to cluster the keywords based on their semantic similarity
        linkage_matrix = linkage(tfidf_matrix.todense(), method="ward")
        res = dendrogram(linkage_matrix, truncate_mode='lastp', p=self.n_clusters, no_plot=True)

        clusters = res['leaves']
        return clusters
```

This will return `[12, 5, 22]` because `self.n_clusters=3` which is normal. So how can I make the association with the keywords?

Comment: So what does `self.vectorizer.fit_transform()` do?

Comment: @ypnos it transforms my list of keywords into vectors using tfidf

Comment: You don't _have_ to supply example data. If you choose not to, then SO contributors won't be able to see what you see when they try out alternative approaches, impacting the quality of responses.